# Ubuntu create-react-app fails with permission denied

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs

I'm getting a weird error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/14/36'atus
```

I just install npm (6.4.1) and node (11.2.0) on an AWS instance without problems. I installed create-react-app globally. The error says `This is an error with npm itself.`

I'm kind of at a loss. I created the directory /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/14 and it still wouldn't succeed. I obviously own and have write permissions in /home/ubuntu.

It looks like it succeeds with sudo. why ?

Edit: ubuntu:ubuntu owns the current and parent directory (I'm in /home/ubuntu/workspace)

Comment: Try installing NodeJS with [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). You won't face problems with permissions

Comment: Try on the command line the following shell command: mkdir - p '/home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/14/36' however, make sure you run the command with the same user ID that you use for the installation. That is just for a quick test! Ops, one more thing to add. You mentioned that you have the answer already :) "It looks like it succeeds with sudo." OK, sudo has write privileges across the entire file system.

Comment: What is the owner and permission of this directory, and **the recursively parent directory**?

Comment: added comment, current users owns (and as I said has write permissions) in the current directory

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**TL;TR**

Run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER '/home/REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME/.npm/'
```

On Linux OS `NPM` and `NodeJS` are installed globally with `sudo` and the owner of that files is the **root** and usually a **user** can only read/execute that packages. When `NPM` is stalled a **~/.npm/** folder is created by the **root**. By running `create-react-app` you are executing the command as **user** and `create-react-app` is trying to modify something in the **~/.npm/** directory which is owned by the **root** and not to current user. You need to change the owner of that directory to you, so you can modify it without `sudo` privileges.

Often similar thing happens when you install `NPM` package with `sudo` e.g. `sudo npm install <package> --save`. Again the newly installed package in owned by the **root** and for example when you try to update/modufy/delete your project without `sudo` infrnt of `NPM` you will have similar permission error. In these cases navigate to your project directory and change its owner by running:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
```

Comment: +1 .... apparently when the first thing I install is with sudo and -g the /home/user/.npm folder isn't owned by me.

Comment: +1. . . thanks for the explanation and answer (newbies like me please change 'home/ubuntu/.npm/' to your own username)

Comment: I'm getting illegal group name? chown: a1621406: illegal group name

Answer (score 8):

## This problem on a Mac

Working from [Reactjs's Getting Started documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app).

#### The Environment

- OSX Mojave `10.14.3`
- NodeJS `v10.15.0`

#### The Error

- Command

  ```
  npx create-react-app my-app
  ```
- Output

  ```
  Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/caseywise/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ae/73'instal
  ```

#### The Fix

> *recursively change `owner`:`group` on **caseywise**'s NPM preferences directory*

```
sudo chown -R caseywise:staff '/Users/caseywise/.npm/'
```

Answer (score 4):

New way of installation will resolve the issue.

According to the latest react documentation follow below steps to create react app

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

> > **Note(from ReactJS Team):** 
> >       If you've previously installed create-react-app
> >     globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you
> >     uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to
> >     ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Refer official documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing **create-react-app: Permission denied** issue with ubuntu 18.04 .I have resolved this issue.

Please execute few commands.

1. Completely uninstall nodejs, npm

   ```
    sudo apt-get remove nodejs
    sudo apt-get remove npm
   ```
2. Check for any .npm or .node folder and delete those.

   ```
    which nodejs
    which node
   ```
3. Install Node.js

   ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install nodejs
   ```
4. The nodejs package contains the nodejs binary as well as npm, so you don’t need to install npm separately.

   Check nodejs and npm version.

   ```
    nodejs --version #v12.22.6
    npm --version    #6.14.15
   ```
5. Create react-app.

   ```
    npm init
    npx create-react-app "your-app-name"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Check the owner of the file with `ls -l /problem/dir/`. The owner is probably set to `root`, instead of `myUserName` (i.e. `TWoody`).

You will want to `ch`ange `own`er of the `.npm/` globally first with `chown`:

`sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.npm/`.

And if this issue has crept into other `/build/` directories after running `npm run build`, you can go to those directories and run the same command:

`sudo chown -R $USER: ./problem/dir/`

Note that the `chown` command is using the `-R` flag to change the user ID and/or group ID for the hierarchies rooted in the files instead of just the files themselves. Also note that the argument `$USER:` is taking your user name (i.e. `myUserName`, `TWoody`) and replacing the "group" ID (the second argument of null) of `root`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove or rename `/home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/`

Answer (score 0):

I have same error on Mac catalina 10.15

You must use sudo, because root is the owner of npm folder, user try to modify some file under npm folder, must run as root by sudo.

The fix is:

```
            sudo dojo create app --name hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R your_user ~/your_projects_directory
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command :

**sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/user/.npm"**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with Windows WSL 2, switching to 'node' user using 'su node' fixed this 'sh: 1: create-react-app: Permission denied' issue. The error was coming when the command 'npx create-react-app test-app' was being executed via 'root'.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above and in the error itself, the issue here is the gap between regular user and su user. The interesting part is, this issue occurs even when you run with sudo permissions i.e. `sudo npx create-react-app app-name`, from what I could gather this happens because the npx command is run in sudo but create-react-app is run as a regular user.

So another solution would be

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app app-name
or
if needed sudo create-react-app app-name(this option not preferred mainly since further activity inside app like npm run start or others might also need usage of sudo)
```

Why I prefer this option is, I would rather have any global npm installation under sudo and only local npm installations under regular user. THis way I dont have to change permissions to the global npm directory.